# Tensorflow CNN filter under constraint

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

**Background**

I am looking to implement a universal image manipulation detection system in tensorflow using CNN as described in this [paper](http://ece.drexel.edu/stamm/papers/Bayar_IHMMSec_2016.pdf).In vanilla CNNs filter values are learnt through backpropagation after their random initialization.

**Problem**

In this implementation the filter values of the first convolution layer are to be re-initialized according to the given constraint(the value of filter centre to -1 and normalize the remaining filter values.) after every iteration.The filter values of rest of the layers are to be trained as in the vanilla case.In tensorflow,the training steps automatically train the filter values too.Is it possible to efficiently apply the given constraint to first layer of filters after every iteration of training using tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

For most training method, for example `tf.train.AdamOptimizer.minimize`, it has a paraeter var_list. By defaut it will update all tensors. If you write, for example, `tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cost, var_list=[W_fc2, b_fc2])`: it will update W_fc2 and b_fc2.